# Using a service during context initaliatizon

Tags: java, spring, servlets, autowired, servletcontextlistener

I have some code I want to initialize in my web application. Before I used it as a @PostConstruct in one of my beans, but it didn't feel quite right to me.
The place to initialize code in the life cycle, is in my opinion, after the servletcontext has initialized.

That's why I wrote a listener class like this:

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    RepairService repairService;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {       

        // Maak een gewone gebruiker
        Address address1 = new Address("Bruul", "5", "2800", "Mechelen");
        Person person1 = new Person("Jan", "Peeters", address1);
        Client client1 = new Client(person1, "jan.peeters@student.kdg.be", "jan");

        // Maak een gewone gebruiker
        Address address2 = new Address("Zandstraat", "23", "3000", "Leuven");
        Person person2 = new Person("Michel", "Van den Bergh", address2);
        Client client2 = new Client(person2, "michel.vandenbergh@gmail.com", "michel");

        // Maak een repairer
        Address address3 = new Address("Nationalestraat", "5", "2000", "Antwerpen");
        Person person3 = new Person("Wouter", "Deketelaere", address3);
        Repairer repairGuy1 = new Repairer(person3, "wouter.deketelaere@kdg.be", "jef", "Master");
        repairGuy1.rate(4);

        // Maak een repairer
        Address address4 = new Address("Kleuterstraat", "1", "2500", "Lier");
        Person person4 = new Person("Handy", "Man", address4);
        Repairer repairGuy2 = new Repairer(person4, "handy.man@handyman.com", "moeilijk", "Bachelor");
        repairGuy2.rate(3);
        // add users and update een gebruiker met een nieuw wachtwoord                
        try
        {
            userService.addUser(client1);
            userService.addUser(client2);
            userService.addUser(repairGuy1);
            userService.addUser(repairGuy2);
            userService.updatePassword(repairGuy1, "jef", "wouter");
            userService.checkLogin(repairGuy1.getUsername(), "wouter");
        }
// ommitted code
```

Now, this doesn't work, and I presume it's because I can't autowire my services so early in the lifecycle. I can't manually construct a new repair- and userservice because these classes are abstract. Should I move my initialization code somewhere else? Or is there a way to do this so early in the lifecycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this using the InitliazingBean interface

Answer (score 1):

There is an interface named

```
 ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>
```

That you could use to initialize something during the startup of the application context within spring application.

```
@Override
    public void initialize(final ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) {
        this.configurableApplicationContext = appContext;

    }
```

Try to create a class that implements that interface and spring will be aware of the initialize method and its content.

Add this to the web.xml

```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
      <param-value>class.to.the.interface.init.RuntimeEnvironmentInitializer</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

Comment: I've tried looking it up a bit on how to configure this, but it seems the code in this method doesn't run. Do I need to add this as a listener in my web.xml or something?

Comment: I should mention I do have this listener in my web.xml     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

Comment: Update in my response, you need to add a context param named contextInitializerClasses in your web.xml and point to the class that implements the interface. check the update

Comment: the services are still null if I do it this way